# Is there any limitation of using selenium hub inside the docker container?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, performance-testing, selenium-grid

Is there any limitation of using selenium hub inside the Docker container?

Use case: Want to use the selenium hub inside the docker container. I am talking about only hub node will be a virtual machine.

Comment: There is no such limitation. Selenium and Docker and independent things. Please elaborate more on your issue.

Answer (score 1):

No limitation, you have an example in this [repository](https://github.com/viltgroup/docker-selenium-grid-extras)